# What is wrong with my code? 5 + 5 will give me 55 instead of 10

Tags: swift, addition

```
@IBAction func calcAns(sender: UIButton) {

   result = firstNumber.text + secondNumber.text
   outputLabel.text = "\(result)"


}
```

What is wrong with my code?  For example 5 + 5 will give me 55 instead of 10. Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: your variable is treated as string instead of int, you need to convert it to int (or cast it)

Comment: `5 + 5 = 10`, but  `"5" + "5" = "55"` .

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answer(s) below, to expression appreciation for the help you have received. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a string to another string:

```
firstNumber.text + secondNumber.text
```

If `firstNumber.text` was "Hello" and `secondNumber.text` was "World", the result would be "HelloWorld". As it is, you're concatenating "5" and "5" to get "55".

The solution would be to convert those strings into **numeric** values before adding them together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string variable to int:

```
@IBAction func calcAns(sender: UIButton) {

   result = firstNumber.text.toInt() + secondNumber.text.toInt()
   outputLabel.text = "\(result)"


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, `+` on strings is concatenation rather than addition.  The `text` property is a string rather than a number.

To convert it to a number, try:

```
if let first = firstNumber.text.toInt(),
       second = secondNumber.text.toInt() {

    outputLabel.text = toString(first + second)

}
```